# How to split a string between two delimiters in php

Tags: php, string, split, delimiter

I would like to split a string from a whole string which has two delimiters. For example

```
String1= ABC*WELCOME*CDF
```

I should get out put as `WELCOME`.

Note: Delimiters can be any position of the string(not static) but I need only string between those two delimiters

Thanks in advance.

Comment: explode on *, then take array index of 1

Comment: @The One and Only ChemistryBlob This fails if the string in the middle have a * in it...

Comment: @fkupper we can only work with the data provided

Comment: @fkupper OP needs to give us more info on characteristics of the string...is it alphabetical only, alphanumeric, special characters allowed, etc.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Agree, just saying because it could lead to wrong conclusions for the OP.

Comment: @fkupper...Yes, all good. To OP: respectfully, please just Google this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$String1 = 'ABC*WELCOME*CDF';
list( ,$myString, ) = explode('*',$String1);
echo $myString;
```

Comment: This fails if the string in the middle have a * in it...